# Listing folder content with React-Router

Tags: javascript, react-router

I am building a "product documentation" web application using React. The application just sits on a shared drive, the user opens index.html and browses the docs. I use React and Bootstrap for getting a nice menu/tree etc. I have  client side code, only.

I also have a bunch of PDF-s organized nicely into folders. The number of files will grow over time. I want the user to be able to browse among the files. I would be happy to have an ordinary anchor tag that opens the appropriate folder in Windows Exporer. This actually does the trick:

```
<a href="./folder_i_want_to_display/" >My product docs</a>
```

However, since I use React Router, the link does not pull up Windows Explorer anymore. Do you have any suggestion?

Browsers:IE10 and 11 only.

Comment: You'd have to get the current route, via `this.props.route.path` and then use javascript or ajax to fetch the folder contents. Just search how to get folder contents in js.